# calculate the user's month of birth from prompt

Tags: javascript

Made a start but I need a tad bit of help...

I'm trying to take a string/answer from what someones given me via a prompt (question is: what month were you born?), taking the first three letters of the answer, converting that to lowercase, then checking with my variable called 'months', if it exists convert to the month as a number.

e.g. If someone entered October, it would change from October to oct to 10 (if that makes sense), I would like to use the answer later in the code... anyway this what I've got so far.

```
var month=prompt("Please enter your month of birth"," "); 
var answer=(month.slice(0,3)); // found string needed


var months = 'janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec';
```

I know that I have to use toLowerCase( ) but don't know how to go about/express that..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would make more sense when you convert October to 9 =).

```
var months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'];
var mindex = months.indexOf(answer.toLowerCase());
```

`mindex` is now a integer ranging from 0 to 11 (jan - dec) =)!